# SQL -- SELECT statement -- concatenate strings to

Tags: sql

I have an SQL question.  Everything works fine in the below SELECT statement except the portion I have highlighted in bold.  What I'm trying to do is allow the user to search for a specific Rule within the database.  Unfortunately, I do not actually have a Rule column, and so I need to concatenate certain field values to create a string with which to compare to the user's searchtext.

Any idea why the part in bold does not work?  In theory, I would like this statement to check for whether the string "Rule " + part_num (where part_num is the value contained in the part_num field) equals the value of searchtext (the value of searchtext is obtained from my PHP script).

I did some research on concatenating strings for SQL purposes, but none seem to fit the bill.  Does someone out there have any suggestions?

```
SELECT id, 
       part_num, 
       part_title, 
       rule_num, 
       rule_title, 
       sub_heading_num, 
       sub_heading, 
       contents 
FROM   rules 
WHERE  part_title LIKE "%'.$searchtext.'%" 
        OR rule_title LIKE "%'.$searchtext.'%" 
        OR sub_heading LIKE "%'.$searchtext.'%" 
        OR contents LIKE "%'.$searchtext.'%" 
        OR "rule" + part_num LIKE "%'.$searchtext.'%"  --RULE PLUS PART_NUM DOESN'T WORK
ORDER  BY id;
```

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: Also, did you mean to say "rule_num" instead of "part_num" ?

Comment: @Tim.  No, part_num is what I meant to say and is the variable I need to use.  Thanks for your suggestions everyone--much appreciated.  I managed to find a solution:  CONCAT("Rule ", part_num)

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify which DB your using, I'm going to assume SQL Sever.

Strings are specified in SQL Server with single quotes `'I'm a string'`, not double quotes.

See [+ (String Concatenation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on MSDN for examples.

Comment: I am using SQL Server, yes.  I changed the double quotes (") to single quotes ('), but now my script returns an error.  This statement works perfectly using double quotes (and when the "rule " + part_num portion is removed).  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Unless I've totally missed something over the years, it is impossible for your SQL statement to `work perfectly` with double quotes...

Comment: Hi James.  The above-mentioned SQL statement is used in my PHP script and it does in fact work perfectly with double-quotes (").  I managed to find a solution:  "CONCAT("Rule ", part_num).

Comment: @ehul: You've introduced a space between the word "rule" and the part_num value in the approach that uses CONCAT().

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that part_num is a numeric. If so, cast the number to a string (varchar) before concatenating.

Comment: this would have to be **in addition** to the double-quote issue.

Comment: @Tim:  Thanks!  I've tried to cast the INT to a string, but now my script returns an error.  I tried: SELECT ID, CAST(partnum AS varchar(5))